# java launching multiple swingworkers from the same UI

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, swingworker, continuous

**Brief description of UI and setup**

1)Plain vanilla frame, with *button1* and *button2* and *textarea1* and *textarea2*

2)*Button1* launches a continuous running task using a swingworker *myswingworker1* and the swingworker's process method continually updates textarea1

3)*Button2* launches a continuous running task using a swingworker *myswingworker2* and the swingworker's process method continually updates textarea2

The continually running task in this case is "adb logcat", this command keeps writing continuous log information to the outstream, that I capture and print to the textarea. this capturing and printing is done inside the swingworker.

**Problem**

Only one one button seems to do the intended task of printing the output to the textarea at a time, either button1 OR button2, whichever was started first. The UI never freezes though.

As a part of the experiment, I replaced one long running task with say a command "dir" which runs and return immediately, ie I attached "dir" to button2. Now if I run *button2*, it works and then *button1* it works too. If I do the other way round only the long running task started by *button1* runs and the task started by *button2* seems to wait for the long running task to end, which defeats the whole purpose of using a swingworker.

How do solve this problem? How do I prevent my UI from waiting for one swingworker to finish?

**code excerpt**

`public class multiswing extends javax.swing.JFrame {`

```
public multiswing() {
    initComponents();
}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    myswingworker1 m1=new myswingworker1(jTextArea1);
    m1.execute();
}

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    myswingworker2 m2=new myswingworker2(jTextArea2);
    m2.execute();
}

/**
* @param args the command line arguments
*/
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new multiswing().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

`public class myswingworker1 extends SwingWorker {`

```
JTextArea jTextArea = new JTextArea();
Process proc;
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

public myswingworker1(JTextArea jTextArea) {
    this.jTextArea = jTextArea;
}

protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

    String line = null;
    rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    proc = rt.exec("adb logcat");
    InputStream stdin = proc.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stdin);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        publish(line);
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
    String data = chunks.get(0);
    jTextArea.append(data + "\n");
}
```

}

`public class myswingworker2 extends SwingWorker {`

```
JTextArea jTextArea = new JTextArea();
Process proc;
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

public myswingworker2(JTextArea jTextArea) {
    this.jTextArea = jTextArea;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

    String line = null;
    rt = Runtime.getRuntime();        
    proc = rt.exec("dir");
    InputStream stdin = proc.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stdin);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        publish(line);
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
    String data = chunks.get(0);
    jTextArea.append(data + "\n");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helped me

http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5434659

Comment: Your link is dead. All I can do is close this out.